# how to handle hairs better in three.js?

Tags: three.js, webgl, alpha

The result I have right now is on the left. I want to make the result close as possbile to the one from the right. Hairs only. [Here's my model.](https://modelviewer.cgig.ru/model?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcgig.ru%2Fdownloads%2Fmodels%2Fcod_bo_cw_pc%2Fcharacters%2FThe_Investigator_Female3.txt)
[image]
How can I achieve that?
here's the code I use right now:

```
m.color.set( 0xffffff );
m.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
m.map.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
m.transparent = true;
m.alphaTest = 0.001;
m.alphaMap = null;
m.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
m.shininess = 6;
m.depthTest = true;
m.depthWrite = true;
m.skinning = true;
m.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

I've tried different variations of code but I don't know the three.js well. I see the problem with sorting, overlapping, etc. How can I can solve this?

I see some succesfull results with webgl here:

- https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/knight-princess-6495fc2ab3ac4fce84315453ab0a6809
- https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/jolly-roser-31008c461a2644ea95f57f938f3e42a8
- https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/subsurface-scattering-sss-demo-lara-a231143a88e44951820bdf11ab4cbf53

Comment: Just pointing out that sketchfab uses a lower-quality rendering for moving frames (while interacting with the mouse) that looks more like your left example, and then performs a high-quality render after user interaction has ceased. You would need to figure out the effects used to perform this high-quality render to even start to match its fidelity.

Comment: Instead of setting `m.alphaTest` (which is a hard threshold between transparent and opaque), try using an `alphaMap` which uses softer transparencies.

Comment: @Marquizzo, I've tried that. Unfortunately it will creates an overlapping issues with polygons which look a lot much worse than this noisy solution.